# Material Ripple Effect for UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cosmicmind

I am trying to create a material ripple effect for a UICollectioView cell. For Android, there are several material design options to do so, but for iOS that does not appear to be the case. Below is my custom cell I am using as the prototype to populate the UICollectioView:

```
import UIKit

class PollCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pollQuestion: UILabel!

}
```

Where I initialize the CollectioViewCell:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    prepareMenuButton()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes

    self.dataSource = self.collectionView?.bind(to: self.ref.child("Polls")) { collectionView, indexPath, snap in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PollCell
        //Here is where I am having issues
        cell.pulseAnimation
        /* populate cell */
        cell.pollQuestion.text = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "question").value as! String?
        let urlPollImage = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "image_URL").value as! String?

        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlPollImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Fan_Polls_Logo.png"))
        //Comment
        return cell
    }
```

Here is an image of one of the cells on a device:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) it has a `CollectionViewCell` that has the pulse animation built in. You can set it with the `pulseAnimation` property. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated with material - can you point out how I should correct my code? Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: `PollCell` should subclass Material's `CollectionViewCell`, which will enable the pulse animations by default. Here is a sample project, [CollectionView](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/CollectionView/CollectionView) to help get you going.

Comment: I got it to work, much appreciated! Now I am simply having difficulty making the cells clickable....

Comment: Are you setting the delegation methods correctly? You should be setting `CollectionVeiwDelegate` and using the `didSelectItemAt` delegation method.

Comment: I am trying to learn all of it. Not sure if it goes in the viewDidLoad() method or not. Additionally, I am using the FirebaseUI which adds another layer of complexity.

Comment: If you look at that sample I sent you, you can see how I set it up, which should be helpful to learn where to put things. Let me know how that goes, and we can go from there :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a CATransition

```
func ripple(view:UIView){
    let ripple = CATransition()
    ripple.type = "rippleEffect"
    ripple.duration = 0.5
    view.layer.add(ripple, forKey: nil)
}
```

you can pass whatever you want to ripple and it will.  Example

```
self.ripple(view: imageView)
```

or you could pass the cell itself on didselect,touches began or whatever you are using to trigger the ripple.

But based on what you are telling me you want a circular pulse to cover the view so I tried this.  I put some libraries to consider in the comments but here is my quick attempt at what you are wanting.

```
var scaleFactor : CGFloat = 0.6
    var animationColor : UIColor = UIColor.green
    var animationDuration : Double = 0.4
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {.  
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let coverView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        coverView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.addSubview(coverView)

        let touch = touches.first!
        let point = touch.location(in: self)

        let ourTouchView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: point.x - 5, y: point.y - 5, width: 10, height: 10))
        print(ourTouchView)
        print(point)


        let circleMaskPathInitial = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ourTouchView.frame)
        let radius = max((self.bounds.width * scaleFactor) , (self.bounds.height * scaleFactor))
        let circleMaskPathFinal = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ourTouchView.frame.insetBy(dx: -radius, dy: -radius))


        let rippleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        rippleLayer.opacity = 0.4
        rippleLayer.fillColor = animationColor.cgColor
        rippleLayer.path = circleMaskPathFinal.cgPath
        coverView.layer.addSublayer(rippleLayer)

        //fade up
        let fadeUp = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeUp.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        fadeUp.duration = animationDuration * 0.6
        fadeUp.toValue = 0.6
        fadeUp.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        fadeUp.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        fadeUp.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rippleLayer.add(fadeUp, forKey: nil)

        //fade down
        let fade = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fade.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + animationDuration * 0.60
        fade.duration = animationDuration * 0.40
        fade.toValue = 0
        fade.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        fade.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        fade.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rippleLayer.add(fade, forKey: nil)

        //change path
        CATransaction.begin()
        let maskLayerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        maskLayerAnimation.fromValue = circleMaskPathInitial.cgPath
        maskLayerAnimation.toValue = circleMaskPathFinal.cgPath
        maskLayerAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        maskLayerAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        maskLayerAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            coverView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
        rippleLayer.add(maskLayerAnimation, forKey: "path")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

I probably would not execute this in touches began and instead use a tap gesture but you could do this.

Comment: How would I set a color that matches the black of the cell? I am thinking a lighter grey, and are you using a third-party library?

Comment: No third party library.  This just makes it look like a water drop.  This is just old school. Are you wanting a color burst from touch event on the location?

Comment: Yes I should have been more specific. I don't even have it wired for touches yet

Comment: So check out that animation and get back to me but to do what you are asking if it is different would be to get the location of the touch and animate a circular view scaling out to completely scale the width and height of the view.  You can use CAShapelayer. https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app or material kit https://github.com/nghialv/MaterialKit

Comment: Check it out now.  I added an animation of a circular pulse using no outside libraries that could be dropped into a collection view cell or any view for that matter.  This might be more what you are looking for